# Iphone Push notifications not working for latest os in php restful api

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I am using the following code for sending iphone notifications. The code is working fine. Notifications ar going to old version os before 7.But notifications are not sending to new os. It is not showing any error. It is showing successfully sent message but messages are not going.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$message="Welcome to 2015";
$passphrase = 'venky';
$badge = 1;
$ck=realpath("ck.pem");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///integrating the ck.pem file to APN's
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $ck);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server

/* $fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx); */

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error,$errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
{
    //return "Failed to iOS connect error: $err $errstr".PHP_EOL;
    print "Failed to connect $error $errorString";
    //exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

$body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,'badge' => $badge,'sound' => 'default');

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
$deviceToken = "a74cad7dbf592073de007c7b830c63889b18610534bbe35ceb989c7bfb30a3eb";
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result) {
    $f+=1;
}
else
{
$s+=1;
}
// Close the connection to the server

//running feedback service
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',$ck);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

    if(!$apns) 
    {
        //echo "ERROR $errcode: $errstr\n";
        return;
    }
    //else echo 'APNS FEEDBACK CONNECTION ESTABLISHED...<br/>';

    $feedback_tokens = array();    
    $count = 0;

    $feedback_tokens = array();
    //and read the data on the connection:
    while(!feof($apns)) {
        $data = fread($apns, 38);
        if(strlen($data)) {
            $feedback_tokens[] = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $data);
        }
    }
    fclose($apns);

if($s>=1)
{
 echo 'Notification sent successfully to '.$s.' iPhone Devices out of '.$s;
 }
else
 echo 'Notification not sent to '.$f.' iPhone Devices out of '.$f;

fclose($fp);

?>
```

i am getting 'Notification sent successfully to 1 iPhone Devices out of 1 ' success message. but notification not going to new iphone os devices. Please help me

Comment: bro problem is in iPhone side

Comment: no issue in iphone side

Comment: handling notification in different OS's is different, if your code working with latest os's then it have to work with old os's too, because you have(means server) only device token and basis on this notification will be pushed to device, you server never now notification will sent on old device os's or new os's. got the point.

Comment: i don't know exactly. but our ios developers said no issue in their side. the code is not working for latest os 8

Comment: he is saying i m not wrong, it not mean you are wrong bro. discuss with your iPhone team and understand the problem, best of luck.

Comment: when i sue sandbox it is working fine. is there any problem in ssl